# bootstrap adds horizontall scroll when I add push and pull in 2 different container-fluids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm adding the following code but I'm getting a horizontal scroll along with overflowing image code in the 1st image within id=1. Which ruins the design. How can I fix this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="1" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4  col-lg-push-1">
                <h1>
                    example</h1>

                <h1>example example example
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-push-3">
                <img src="img/example.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="2" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-pull-2">
                 <img src="img/example2.png">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-2">
               <h1> example</h1>

                <h1>example example example</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=320, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi"/>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>test </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/css/BootstrapXL.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.4/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazy/1.7.4/jquery.lazy.plugins.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var imgs = $('img'); //grabbing all the images of a DOM
            imgs.addClass('lazy'); //adding .lazy to all the images
            imgs.each(function () {
                var img_src = $(this).attr('src'); //grabbing the 'src=""' value of each of the img
                $(this).attr('data-src', img_src); //assigning the src value to 'data-original'
                $(this).removeAttr('src'); //now deleting the 'src' attribute
            });

            /**
             * ...And here we are initiating our LazyLoad jQuery plugin to all the images
             * that has a class '.lazy'
             */
            $(function () {
                $("img.lazy").lazy();
            });

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body style="background: cornflowerblue">

<!-- Static navbar -->
<div id="topbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a id="2" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">test
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="tabs" href="1.html">1</a></li>
                <li><a class="tabs" href="2.html">2</a></li>
                <li><a class="tabs" href="3.html">3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function Scroll() {
        var top = document.getElementById('topbar');
        var ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        if (ypos > 300) {
            top.style.height = "70px";
            top.style.paddingTop = "10px";
        }
        else {
            top.style.height = "192px";
            top.style.paddingTop = "70px";
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", Scroll);

</script>


<div id="1">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-2" style="margin-top: 80px;">
                <h1 id="id1">test</h1>
                <h3>example</h3>
                <p style="margin-top: 35px;"
                   class="p_justify">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                    Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
                    a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                    popularised in the 19</p>

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 200px; ">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-push-1 hidden-xs">
                <div class="col-lg-6  ">
                    <h1 style="font-size: 20px;color: #FFFFFF;letter-spacing: -0.29px;">
                        test
                        example</h1>
                    <h3 style="color: #FFFFFF;letter-spacing: -0.38px; margin-top: 50px;">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's sta</h3>
                    <button style="background: #24262B;color: white;margin-top: 100px;">button
                    </button>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/wc-prod-pim/JPEG_1000x1000/IP7P128SG_iphone_7_plus_128gb_black.jpg"
                         class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>


            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /col-lg-8 -->
    </div><!-- /row -->
</div> <!-- /container-fluid -->



<div id="5" style="margin-top: 400px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4  col-lg-push-1">
                <h1 style="font-family: Helvetica-Bold;font-size: 20px;color: #FFFFFF;letter-spacing: -0.29px;">
                    test</h1>

                <h1 style="font-size: 39px;color: #FFFFFF;letter-spacing: -0.38px;">example example
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-push-1">
                <img src="http://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/spacee.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="6" style="margin-top: 400px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4  col-lg-push-1">
                <h1 style="
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
letter-spacing: -0.29px;">
                    test example</h1>

                <h1 style="
font-size: 39px;
color: #FFFFFF;
letter-spacing: -0.38px;">test est test
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-push-1">
                <img src="http://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/spacee.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<div id="7">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 200px; ">
            <div class="">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-pull-1">
                    <img src="http://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/spacee.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6  col-lg-push-1" style="margin-top: 600px;">
                    <h1 style="
font-size: 20px;
color: #FFFFFF;
letter-spacing: -0.29px;">
                        test example</h1>

                    <h1
                            style="
font-size: 39px;
color: #FFFFFF;
letter-spacing: -0.38px;">examPLE example example
                    </h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>






</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Which version of bootstrap? Could you please use a code snippet where the version of bootstrap you are using is included?

Comment: @Connum I've updated the bootstrap code. Please have a look.

Comment: I updated your question using a working code snippet. As you can see, it's not possible for anyone trying to help you to comprehend the actual problem. Please provide enough information so that we can see the issue and help you fix it.

Comment: @Connum I've added full code :)